# React: how to update a deep property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the simple state:

```
const state = {
    title: "The title",
    colorSet: {
        multiple: true,
        colors: [
            'red',
            'green',
            'blue',
            'yellow',
            'gray',
            'white',
        ],
        selected: [
            'green',
            'yellow',
        ],
    }
};
```

We are to pass into the `setState()` function only the changes what we need *to apply*. For example, if I need to update the `title` only then I do it: `this.SetState({title:"Updated title"})`. But what I am to do if I need update more deeply property, for example: `state.colorSet.selected`?

It doesn't work: `this.setState({ colorSet: { selected }})`. Can I pass into `setState()` only the changes instead of passing full deep clone of my state with applied the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to update deep nested property, it's better to this way:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({colorSet: {...prevState.colorSet, selected: newSelectedArray }}))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use spread operator on nested properties to not mutate the original object

```js
const state = {
    title: "The title",
    colorSet: {
        multiple: true,
        colors: [
            'red',
            'green',
            'blue',
            'yellow',
            'gray',
            'white',
        ],
        selected: [
            'green',
            'yellow',
        ],
    }
};

const a = {
    ...state,
  colorSet: { ...state.colorSet, selected: [ ...state.colorSet.selected, 'black']}
  }
console.log(a)
```

Comment: I know, but it can be tediously for complex state.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function which accepts the current state as an argument and only passing the changed value.

```
this.setState((currentState) => {
   return {
      ...currentState,
      colorSet: {
            ...currentState.colorSet,
            selected
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with nested objects, instead of directly mutating the state, you should create a copy of the top level object that you want to update. After that, make a copy of the nested object that you want to mutate. Then update the top level copied object and finally update the state.

In short, you have to rebuild the top-level object. In your case, you will have to rebuild `colorSet` object.

```
// make a copy of colorSet object
const colorSetCopy = { ...this.state.colorSet };
// make a copy of the selected array
const selectedCopy = [...colorSetCopy.selected];
// update selectedCopy 
selectedCopy.push('red');
// update colorSetCopy
colorSetCopy.selected = selectedCopy;
// finally update the state
this.setState({ colorSet: colorSetCopy });
```

You can combine above steps as:

```
const selectedCopy = [...this.state.colorSet];
selectedCopy.push('red');
this.setState(prevState => (
     { colorSet: {...prevState.colorSet, selected: selectedCopy} }
));
```

> Can I pass into setState() only the changes instead of passing full
> deep clone of my state with applied the changes?

That will be mutating the state directly and you shoudn't do that.

From the [React Docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is
> being applied. It should not be directly mutated. Instead, changes
> should be represented by building a new object based on the input from
> state and props.

In functional components, if you have complex objects in the state, it is better to use `useReducer` hook instead of `useState` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let newState = this.state;
newState.colorSet.selected = selected;
this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: You mean `newState.colorSet.selected = selected;`. But at this case `newState` is not a full deep clone of original. Can I have a problem related with it later?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Fixed in the answer. Not as far as I'm concerned. SetState should take care of the updating. If not, try this:
`let newState = {...this.state};`

Answer (score 0):

As several people already told you, most usual way to solve this is using spread operator. But I think best way to avoid having those complex nested state structure is to refactor your stateful components to use react hooks. In that way you can set a `useState` hook per state domain meaning, reducing then each state scope.

With the given example, I would probably use 3 states here: `title`, `colorSet` and `colorsSetSeleted`.

Here you can find docs about this hook usage: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html